# C++ Global class variables are not created

Tags: c++, global-variables

Iam looking at a piece of code that creates global class variables. The constructors of these classes calls a symbol table singleton and adds the this pointers in it..

In a Keywords.cpp file

```
class A : class KeyWord
{
  A() { add(); }
} A def;
```

similarly for keywords B,C etc

```
void KeyWord::add()
{
 CSymbolCtrl& c = CSymbolCtrl::GetInstance();
 c.addToTable(this);
}
```

These translation units are compiled to form a library. When i "dumpbin" the library, i see the dynamic initializers for ADef, BDef etc.

No in the exe, when i call the CSymbolCtrl instance, i didnt find the ADef, BDef.. stored in its map. When i set a breakpoint in add(), its not getting hit. Is there a way that the linker is ignoring ADef, BDef because they are not referenced anywhere?

}

Comment: Could you use plausibly-compilable sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Standard docs *1.9 Program execution*,

> 4) This provision is sometimes called the “as-if” rule, because an implementation is free to disregard any requirement of this International Standard
>   as long as the result is as if the requirement had been obeyed, as far as can be determined from the observable behavior of the program. For instance,
>   an actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no side effects affecting the
>   observable behavior of the program are produced.

So, it *might*, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. A pretty common way to force registration is to do something like:

```
static bool foo = register_type();
```

Comment: Is there a way to force the linkers not to ignore these variables?

Comment: @user97642: in the relevant tranlation unit, just add some function. call that function. that may sound like magic, but standard requires that static variables be initialized before that call, so it introduces a dependency. cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach, Does an empty usage like `def;` somewhere ain't enough? Or it does require to call a function from it?

Comment: @liaK: C++98 §3.6.2/3 says (after noting that it's implementation defined whether initialization is done before first statement of `main`): "If the initialization is deferred to some point after the first statement of `main`, it shall occur before the first use of any function or object defined in the same translation unit as the object to be initialized". So standard-wise you'd be on safe ground. But I just have a gut feeling that a compiler might erroneously optimize away an empty reference to an object, so I'd use a function. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @ Alf P. Steinbach, Yeah, true. But I thought in this case, just for the sake of usage, defining a function seems to be odd. IMO though... :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear from your question, but are you actually
including the compiled object files in your link or not?  Just
putting a file in a library doesn't cause it to be included in
the final program.  By definition, a file from a library will
only be included in the executable if it resolves an unresolved
external symbol.  If you want an object file to be part of the
final executable, and it doesn't contain any globals which would
resolve an undefined external, then you have several choices:

-- Link the object file directly, rather than putting it in
    a library.  (This is the "standard" or "canonical" way of
    doing it.)

-- Use a DLL.  Dispite the name, DLL's are not libraries, but
    object files, and are linked in an all or nothing way.

-- Create a dummy global symbol, and reference it somewhere.
    (This can often be automated, and might be the preferred
    solution if you're delivering a library as a third party
    supplier.)